# How filter tables in sql in group

Tags: sql

I have two tables.

```
Customer                      |      OrderItems

CustomerID CustomerName       |      OrderItemID OrderID   CustomerID        Status

    1          ABC            |          1          1          1            Started
                                         2          1          1            Started
                              |          3          1          1            NotStarted
```

Now I want to get the record of all the customer where the status of orderItems is Completed. Means in this case the order is incomplete.

so If I want to get the status of incomplete orders it should give me for customer 1 is order1.

even though the items are started of 1st two but still I want to get that Incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

```
select OrderID, CustomerID, 
       SUM(case Status when 'NotStarted' Then 1 Else 0) NS
from OrderItems
group by OrderID, CustomerID
having NS > 0;
```

Comment: But it do contain NotStarted for one Item.then How will this be considered as complete ? I want whether the order is complete or not. I dont want that is it started or not

Comment: @AnalKukadiya Now I think I understand your question, please try the updated sql

Comment: Will I require group by clause ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood you correctly, but this should do the job:

```
select distinct c.CustomerId, oi.OrderId
from Customer c
inner join OrderItems oi on c.CustomerID = oi.CustomerID
where c.OrderId not in (select o.OrderId from OrderItems o where o.Status <> 'Started')
```

Comment: But it do contain NotStarted for one Item.then How will this be considered as complete ? I want whether the order is complete or not. I dont want that is it started or not

Comment: Fixed my query, try again.

Answer (score 0):

### select c.customerId,c.Customername,O.OrderID, from Customer c left join OrderItem O on C.customerID = o.OrderID where o.Status = 'started'

Comment: you can add required fields of tables respectively

Answer (score 0):

```
select OrderID, CustomerID, 
       SUM(case Status when 'Started' Then 0 Else 1) NS
from OrderItems
having NS > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the customers with NO INCOMPLETE ORDERS, then this should do the trick:

```
SELECT C.CustomerID, C.CustomerName
FROM Customer AS C
WHERE (((C.CustomerID) Not In 
   (SELECT DISTINCT [O].CustomerID
    FROM OrderItems AS O
    WHERE ((([O].Status)="NotStarted")))));
```

I miss something though: I think there should be an ORDER table with information regarding the order. Data in your OrderItems table would be inconsistent if you changed the customerID for one record let's say for OrderItemID = 3 the clientID is 2. Are there two different clients for the same order? I suppose that you didn't handle all the information and that there *is* an Order table.

Regards,